# Newly created parent theme not detected in Moodle Theme Selector

Tags: php, themes, moodle, moodle-theme

I am developing a fresh parent theme in moodle. My moodle build version is 20231211. I have created a barebone structure of all necessary files and it looks like below:

```
oneui
├── README.md
├── classes
│   └── output
│       └── renderer.php
├── config.php
├── image.png
├── lang
│   └── en
│       └── theme_oneui.php
├── pix
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── screenshot.png
├── screenshots
│   ├── config.png
│   ├── folder.png
│   ├── lang.png
│   ├── output1.png
│   ├── output2.png
│   ├── output3.png
│   └── version.png
├── settings.php
├── styles
│   └── styles.css
├── theme_oneui.php
└── version.php
```

Source code for the same can be found in https://github.com/SRRInternational/moodle-parent-theme.git

There are no errors after adding the theme in moodle theme folder.
[image]

**Issue:**
My newly created theme, isn't listed in Appearance -> Theme Selector view. Please advice where I can look and what could be causing this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the Layouts of your theme.

From [Moodle documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Themes_overview):

> "All themes are required to define the layouts they wish to be
> responsible for as well as create; however, many layout files are
> required by those layouts. If the theme is overriding another theme
> then it is a case of deciding which layouts this new theme should
> override. If the theme is a completely fresh start then you will need
> to define a layout for each of the different possibilities."

So, you need to create the `layout` directory and create the PHP files inside with the layout settings of your theme.

Answer (score 0):

This is a the documentation on themes and layouts in moodle: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Themes_overview I did a quick search and quickly realized you need to create a layout for your theme.

Hope this helps! :)